# 404で延々とクローリングされる、これはなに？　→ /data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP/yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7

Tags: apache, nginx

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [16/Mar/2015:11:05:16 +0900] "GET /data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP/yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7 HTTP/1.1" 404 162 "-" "Wing/2 (GM 1.3.5)" "-"
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [16/Mar/2015:11:05:41 +0900] "GET /data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP/yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7 HTTP/1.1" 404 162 "-" "Wing/2 (GM 1.3.5)" "-"
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [16/Mar/2015:11:06:09 +0900] "GET /data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP/yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7 HTTP/1.1" 404 162 "-" "Wing/2 (GM 1.3.5)" "-"
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [16/Mar/2015:11:08:39 +0900] "GET /archives/data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP/yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7 HTTP/1.1" 404 53839 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (jig browser web; 1.0.4; F09A3)" "-"
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [16/Mar/2015:11:09:14 +0900] "GET /data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP/yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7 HTTP/1.1" 404 162 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (jig browser web; 1.0.4; N03D)" "-"
```

nginxのaccess logです。あるクローラーが404にも関わらず延々と走ってきます。

「R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP/yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7」で検索してみると、透明な最小git画像？のdata URIのようでした。
[Smallest data URI image possible for a transparent image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018611/smallest-data-uri-image-possible-for-a-transparent-image)

これらを404で受け付けたくないので、403を返しておけば問題ないでしょうか？それとも何か意味がありますか？

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP/yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7`はdataスキームによる埋め込み画像です。`<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP/yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7">`で、**対応しているUA(ブラウザ)であれば**画像が表示されます。

**対応しているUA(ブラウザ)であれば**というのがポイントで、対応していないUAだとそれを普通にパスと見なしてサーバにリクエストを投げる場合があります。その場合は(偶然の一致が無い限り)サーバ上では404になるでしょう。

運用上404と403に重要な区別があるなどの事情があれば403になるようにしても問題ありません。一般論であれば、そうしたところでリクエストが減るようなものでもないので意味はありません。このようなリクエストを減らしたいのであればコンテンツ側でブラウザを判別し埋め込み画像を使うかどうかを変える必要があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。結局のところ、外部プラグイン内にdataスキームがあって、仰るとおり解釈出来てなかったのかと思います。プラグインを外すことにしました。

Answer (score 1):

又聞きになりますが、jig browserがdata schemeに対応しておらず、画像ファイルとしてフェッチしに来ると聞きました。403でokだと思います。

Answer (score 0):

1x1 ピクセルの透明画像は大抵、1 px のボーダーを描きたい時や、要素と要素の間を開けるためのスペーサーに使われます。

Osamu Nishiyama さんのサーバ上で JavaScript, HTML, CSS 上にて上記の画像を使うようなコードを記述してはいませんか？
もし提供している覚えが無い時は 404 で返すのでもいいですし、403 で返しても問題ないと思います。

Comment: lazy_load関連の外部プラグインでその記述がありました。一旦止めて様子みることにします。